# How to pass extra parameters on extension's class from main config?

Tags: php, yii

I have a third party class ( in extension/MYClass folder ) which constructor requires two necessity parameters.

```
class MyClass {
   function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3 = false) {
    $this->param1 = $param1;
    $this->param2 = $param2;
    $this->param3 = $param3;
  }
  public static function send(){
    ---------
    ---------
  }
}
```

When I go through the  main config file to access that class like this. Then How should I pass those params on that class?

```
'components'=>array(
        'myclass' => array(
                    'class' => 'ext.MyClass.MyClass',
            ),
),
```

So that I can easily access the function like `Yii::app()->myclass->send();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should have MyClass extend `CApplicationComponent` if you havn't already done so.

Then it's just a matter of supplying the params a `key => value` pair to the config.

```
'components'=>array(
        'myclass' => array(
                    'class' => 'ext.MyClass.MyClass',
                    'myParam' => 'test'
            ),
),
```

And setting up the class properly.

```
   class MyClass extends CApplicationComponent {
      public $myParam
      public function send(){
         echo $this->myParam;
      }
    }
```

The above would echo `test` for the call `Yii::app()->myclass->send()`